# embedly / jquery-preview for rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, embed

I'm trying to pull out the specific variables from the embedly callback.  Right now the form works, and the preview is generated.  However, none of the individual variables can be called.

This is my original embedly code in my view:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="span10 columns offset3">
          <h3>Share a link</h3>
          <form id="preview_form" class="form-vertical" method="post" action=".">
            <fieldset>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <label for="url">URL</label>
                <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" name="url" id="id_url" />
                <span class="help-block">Enter a url.</span>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            <!-- Placeholder that tells Preview where to put the loading icon-->
            <div class="loading">
              <img src='http://embedly.github.com/jquery-preview/images/loading-rectangle.gif'>
            </div>
            <!-- Placeholder that tells Preview where to put the selector-->
            <div class="selector"></div>

            <div class="actions">
              <input id="id_submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post"/>
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div id="feed" class="span10 columns offset3">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<script>
      var preview = {
        submit : function(e, data){
          e.preventDefault();
          this.display.create(data);
        }
      }
      $('#id_url').preview({key:'my_key',
                            preview:preview,
                            selector : {type:'rich'},
                            maxwidth : 500,
                            display : {display : 'rich'}});
</script>
```

It works great.  However, I want to get the individual variables into a template (below being the template).  Any suggestions on how to do either this or to pull into the view?  Right now {{title}} displays as {{title}} and not the actual title, along with all other variables.

```
<div id="selector" class="small">
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="controls">
          <a class="left" href="#">&#9664;</a>
          <a class="right" href="#">&#9654;</a>
          <a class="nothumb" href="#">&#10005;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="items">
          <ul class="images">
            {{#images}}
            <li><img src="{{url}}"/></li>
            {{/images}}
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="attributes">
        <a class="title" href="#">{{title}}</a>
        <p><a class="description" href="#">{{description}}</a></p>
        <span class="meta">
          <img class="favicon" src="{{favicon_url}}">
          <a class="provider" href="{{provider_url}}">{{provider_display}}</a>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="action"><a href="#" class="close">&#10005;</a></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#id_url').preview({key:'my_key',
                        preview:preview,
                        selector : {type:'rich'},
                        maxwidth : 500,
                        display : {display : 'rich'}}
                        success : function(oembed){
                                  oembed.title // gives you title
                                  oembed.description // gives you description 
                                  });
```

You can use them and style them the way you want. But this will override the default embedly styles.